# glDrawArrays Draws Nothing

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, glfw

I am trying to learn OpenGL. Fist I completed some WebGL tutorials, to understand how shaders work and how to use them with OpenGL code.

I just wanted to take a step forward and implement some graphics with LWJGL.

In code, i call glDrawArrays function as I did in webgl but that draws nothing.

Here is my vertex shader:

```
void main(){
   gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);
   gl_PointSize = 50.0;
}
```

And fragment shader:

```
void main(){
    gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0);
}
```

And here is the java code that I use to render a point:

```
package com.harvester.game;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.IntBuffer;
import com.harvester.game.loaders.ShaderLoader;
import static org.lwjgl.glfw.GLFW.glfwMakeContextCurrent;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL20.*;
import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;
import static org.lwjgl.system.MemoryStack.*;

public class GamePlayState implements GameState {
    private StateManager stateManager;
    long window;
    int program;

    public GamePlayState(StateManager stateManager, long window) {
        this.stateManager = stateManager;
        this.window = window;
    }

    @Override
    public void init() {
        // Make the OpenGL context current
        glfwMakeContextCurrent(window);
        createCapabilities();
        initShaders();

        System.out.println("OpenGL version " + glGetString(GL_VERSION));
    }

    @Override
    public void load() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("load");
        glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    }

    @Override
    public void update() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // System.out.println("update");
    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        // glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        // System.out.println(60/(delta/1000));

        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 2);
        // System.out.println(glGetError());

        // glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
    }

    @Override
    public void destroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    private void initShaders() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // System.out.println("init");
        String fragmentShaderCode = "";
        String vertexShaderCode = "";
        try {
            fragmentShaderCode = ShaderLoader.LoadFragmentShaderSource();
            vertexShaderCode = ShaderLoader.LoadVertexShaderSource();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }

        int program = glCreateProgram();
        int fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        int vertextShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);

        glShaderSource(vertextShader, vertexShaderCode);
        glCompileShader(vertextShader);

        IntBuffer statsB = stackPush().mallocInt(1);
        glGetShaderiv(vertextShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, statsB);

        if (statsB.get(0) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Failed to compile vertex shader");
            System.exit(-2);
        }

        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderCode);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);

        glGetShaderiv(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS, statsB);

        if (statsB.get(0) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Failed to compile fragment shader");
            System.exit(-3);
        }

        glAttachShader(program, vertextShader);
        glAttachShader(program, fragmentShader);

        glLinkProgram(program);

        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_LINK_STATUS, statsB);

        if (statsB.get(0) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Failed to link Program");
            System.exit(-4);
        }


        glValidateProgram(program);
        glGetProgramiv(program, GL_VALIDATE_STATUS, statsB);

        System.out.println(glGetProgramInfoLog(program));

        glUseProgram(program);

        if (statsB.get(0) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.err.println("Failed to validate program");
            System.exit(-3);
        }

        this.program = program;
    }
}
```

What am I doing wrong? I just want to draw a small smiling point to my screen.

(Debug option set to true but logs shows nothing wrong.)

Comment: Which OpenGL version and profile are you targeting? If you have a core profile, using a VAO is mandatory.

Comment: Logged version information to console it's OpenGL version 2.1 INTEL-10.25.17.

Comment: @BDL looking at his imports it doesn't look like it

Comment: Updated code, removed unused imports. But still, LWJGL forces me to import GL11 packages to use GL_FALSE etc.

Comment: Next try :) If your window is double buffered, you need to call glClear and glfwSwapBuffers in the render method. If it is single buffered, you should call `glFlush`.

Comment: It didn't helped me, i changed my render function to:     public void render(float delta) {
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); 
        glfwSwapBuffers(window); // swap the color buffers
        glDrawArrays(GL_POINTS, 0, 1);
        
    }

Comment: Where do you create/initialize your vertex buffer object?  Is that done elsewhere?

Comment: The call to glfwSwapBuffers has to be after glDrawArrays.

Comment: Try `gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.5, 0.0, 0.0);` instead of `gl_Position = vec4(0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0);`.

Comment: I tried every suggestion made by you, at last, i used glBindAttribLocation and draw a triangle, but still i can not draw a single point :)